# Algebra question, Cardano's method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the following information:

$$a^3 + b^3 = -q $$

$$a^3b^3 = -\dfrac{p^3}{27}$$

Apparently this yields the equation $z^2 + qz -\dfrac{p^3}{27}$ of which $a^3$ and $b^3$ are the roots.

Can someone explain this to me? I don't understand why this is the case.

Comment: If two numbers $a$ and $b$ sum to $s$ and their product is $p$, then they are the roots of the quadratic equation $z^2-sz+p=0$, because it factors as $(z-a)(z-b)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you have the equations $u+v=S$, $uv=P$. First note that the roots of the equation
$(X-u)(X-v)=0$ are $u$ and $v$. But
$$(X-u)(X-v)=X^2-(u+v)X+uv=X^2-SX+P$$

That is, if you know that the sum of a pair of numbers is $S$ and their product is $P$, you can state that the roots of the equation $X^2-SX+P=0$ are precisely these numbers.

Now, let $u=a^3$, $v=b^3$, $S=-q$, $P=-\frac{p^3}{27}$.